# Trying to scroll up a scrollview in all apis

Tags: android, api, scrollview, compatibility

I'm using the next source code to scroll up a scrollview, but I've saw that the method removeOnGlobalLayoutListener isn't compatible under API 16.

```
public void scrollUp(){
        // Wait until my scrollView is ready
        sv_container.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ready, move up
                sv_container.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                sv_container.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
```

Did you know a way to achieve this purpose in all APIs? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a deprecated method that does the same thing - 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener).

Just make sure to use the new one where available.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

```
public void scrollUp(){
        // Wait until my scrollView is ready
        sv_container.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ready, move up
                sv_container.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    sv_container.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    sv_container.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```